# Transform dataframe to binary dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, melt

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups Names
G1     SP1
G1     SP2
G1     SP3
G2     SP1
G2     SP4
G3     SP2
G3     SP1
```

And I would like to transform it as :

```
  Names G1 G2 G3
  SP1   1  1  1
  SP2   1  0  1  
  SP3   1  0  0 
  SP4   0  1  0
```

Where in columns are the `Groups`
and within cell **1 = present** and **0 = absent**

Here is the dput format

```
structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3", 
"G3"), Names = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP1", "SP4", "SP2", "SP1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: 1> `with(your_data_frame, table(Names, Groups))`; 2> `xtabs(~ Names + Groups, your_data_frame)`; 3> `xtabs(~ Names + Groups, your_data_frame, sparse = TRUE)`

Comment: It is rather frustrating. My comment reached you first, and I posted an answer later. Yet you accepted another answer which is covered by my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `table`:

```
table(df$Names, df$Groups)
     
      G1 G2 G3
  SP1  1  1  1
  SP2  1  0  1
  SP3  1  0  0
  SP4  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding comment to an answer.

This is known as a contingency table, and can be computed in several ways, without using fancy packages.

```
dat <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3", 
"G3"), Names = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP1", "SP4", "SP2", "SP1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

mat1 <- with(dat, table(Names, Groups))
#     Groups
#Names G1 G2 G3
#  SP1  1  1  1
#  SP2  1  0  1
#  SP3  1  0  0
#  SP4  0  1  0

mat2 <- xtabs(~ Names + Groups, dat)
#     Groups
#Names G1 G2 G3
#  SP1  1  1  1
#  SP2  1  0  1
#  SP3  1  0  0
#  SP4  0  1  0
```

Such table is a matrix. If you want a data frame, coerce them using:

```
data.frame(unclass(mat1))
#    G1 G2 G3
#SP1  1  1  1
#SP2  1  0  1
#SP3  1  0  0
#SP4  0  1  0

data.frame(unclass(mat2))
#    G1 G2 G3
#SP1  1  1  1
#SP2  1  0  1
#SP3  1  0  0
#SP4  0  1  0
```

---

**Remark:**

In your case, your data frame should have no duplicated rows, otherwise a contingency table won't just contain 0 and 1. In this sense, computing a contingency table actually overkills. An algorithmically simpler way (although with more lines of code) is:

```
m1 <- unique(dat$Names)
m2 <- unique(dat$Groups)
mat <- matrix(0, length(m1), length(m2), dimnames = list(m1, m2))
mat[with(dat, cbind(Names, Groups))] <- 1
#    G1 G2 G3
#SP1  1  1  1
#SP2  1  0  1
#SP3  1  0  0
#SP4  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` over `df` either by

```
> t(table(df))
     Groups
Names G1 G2 G3
  SP1  1  1  1
  SP2  1  0  1
  SP3  1  0  0
  SP4  0  1  0
```

or

```
> table(rev(df))
     Groups
Names G1 G2 G3
  SP1  1  1  1
  SP2  1  0  1
  SP3  1  0  0
  SP4  0  1  0
```